# Date picker not shown on the first component click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have the following code in my JSP and I bind the variables with knockout js.

My js is

```
 calender: function () {
     console.log("in calender");
     var dates = $("#from1, #to1").datepicker({
     defaultDate: "+1w",
     changeMonth: true,
     numberOfMonths: 1,
     onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
         var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
             instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
             date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
             instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
         dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
     }
 });
 },
```

**and the jsp is**

```
 <div class="DateRange">
 <label for="from">From</label>
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from" data-bind="click: calender, value:    starDate"/>
 <label for="to">to</label>
 <input type="text" id="to" name="to" data-bind="click: calender, value: endDate"/>
 </div>
```

The calender method is getting called when I click on either start or end end date, but the issue is the date picker is not shown for click (just method alone called) on the fisrt component for very first time regardless if its id. from the next click on the second component only the datepicker is coming up fine. Any thing I'm missing here?

Comment: See my answer below, the input is not a datapicker() until the calendar method runs the first time, that initializes the datapicker for the input. On the second click the datapicker works since it was initialized on the first pass through the calendar method.

Answer (score 0):

In a few words 
 1. Move datapicker initialization out of calendar method.
 2. Create two separate method for each field which will show appropriate datepicker i.e.:

```
    $("#from1, #to1").datepicker({
     defaultDate: "+1w",
     changeMonth: true,
     numberOfMonths: 1,
     onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
         var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
             instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
             date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
             instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
         dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);

      }
    });    

    ........

    calenderFrom: function () {
     $("#from1").datepicker("show");
    }
    calenderTo: function () {
     $("#to1").datepicker("show");
    }

<input type="text" id="from" name="from" data-bind="click: calenderFrom, value:    starDate"/>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" data-bind="click: calenderTo, value: endDate"/>
```

**UPD**
I assume you use jQueryUI datepicker. If so you don't really need to show it manually; just initialize it

Comment: is there any way to initialize the datepicker in the same calender method? Having these as a separate methods giving compilations errors in the js in our view model.

Answer (score 0):

It's not firing because the input is not actually a datapicker() until it gets through the calendar method the first time. The second time you click the input is a datapicker because it was set on the first pass of the calendar method.

Why not just do this instead of using the calendar method:

```
$("#from1, #to1").datepicker({...});
```